# Setting up React, Bable environment. Complaining on the first "<" in the HTML layout

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

So, I am stuck on this error:
[image]

[image]

Babel seems to work fine. It makes all the changes to the file in another folder. I guess I have all the necessary dependencies installed.

Package.json :

```
{
  "name": "indecision-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "Dima",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.5.2",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.7"
  },
}
```

After some researching it seems that the code doesn't properly update the HTML file after a couple of changes to the dependencies (I tried several versions), or something with connection app.js file to HTML. But I don't know how to approach this, particularly in my environment.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Indecision App</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/public/scripts/app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
console.log('App.js is running, but not really!');

// JSX - JavaScript XML
var template = (
  <div>
    <h1>Indecision App</h1>
    <p>This is some info</p>
    <ol>
      <li>Item one</li>
      <li>Item two</li>
    </ol>
  </div>
);

var appRoot = document.getElementById("app");

ReactDOM.render(template, appRoot);
```

Comment: Is this happening when you are trying to access a nested route? Or all the time? Try setting a `base` element in your html.

Comment: @KyleRichardson What should I put inside `base` tag?

Comment: Whatever the base url of your application is. Most likely `<base href='/'>

Comment: That error means it cannot find app.js where you say it is. Put your mouse over the underlined app.j in the error and see what directory it is trying to load the file from.

Comment: Still nothing :(
`<base href="/public/scripts/app.js">`